# Axios Vue app only Post Request Network error

Tags: node.js, express, http, axios, postman

Using the Following Stack Express,Vue,SQL,Axios

1. GET request is working fine in postman as well from Axios
2. POST request created error in both attached screenshots
3. To make sure the Backend is working fine I have tried sending the Data directly from

```
<form action="url" method="POST">
```

it is Working fine and data is storing in the database

I have Tried few workaround like disabling SSL setting in postman and Played with proxy setting  Also having CORS enabled in the backend and tried some Allow content and header things. Nothing worked

Not able to figure out the Problem in the POST Request. Please Help

--Request Error in the browser from Axios ----
[Axios Browser Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afoW6.png)

-postman Error when doing POST Request---
[Postman Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYIjM.png)

---Backend Index.js file---

```
// const express = require("express");
"use strict";

import express from "express";
const app = express();
import cors from "cors";

//listening on this port
app.listen(3000);

app.use(cors()); // to get Data from Other Domains

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("Application Started");
  console.log("Application Started");
});

//Routes
app.use("/product", require("./routes/product"));
```

---product.js routes files---

```
import express from "express";
const router = express.Router();
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

//Middleware
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // To Parse the body data

//Importing Main Controller
import conProduct from "../controllers/ConProduct";

//Defining functions as per Routes
router.post("/add", conProduct.add); //Showing all the products
router.get("/get", conProduct.get); //Showing all the products

//Exporting Router
module.exports = router;
```

---Controller for Product file ConProducts.js ---

```
import sqlConfig from "../database/dbConfig";
let sql = sqlConfig.mysql_pool;

exports.add = (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const { name, shortDescription, price, discount } = req.body;

  let addQuery =
    "INSERT INTO products(name,short_description,price,discount) VALUES('" +
    name +
    "','" +
    shortDescription +
    "','" +
    price +
    "','" +
    discount +
    "');";

  sql.query(addQuery, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    res.send("product uploaded");
  });
};
```

--Frontend axios Request --

```
let formData = {
        name: this.name,
        shortDescription: this.shortDescription,
        price: this.price,
        discount: this.discount,
      };
      console.log(formData);
      axios
        .post("/product/add", formData)
        .then((res) => console.log(res))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Comment: In the screen shout I see you using `PUT` instead of `POST` can you please validate if this is a typo or the issue?

Comment: Hey daniel thats a typo i have tried post as well

Comment: @Kamran Memon Just a tip when you are debugging from `Front-end` to `Back-end` and vice versa, open your browser's developer tools and on the network tab you can see all the requests made along with the request/response headers, body, status and other useful information.

Comment: @vchan thanks allot will keep that in mind any help with the error

Comment: @Daniel any help ? regarding the Issue will be a big help

Comment: hey @KamranMemon , I have seen connection refused error. `app.listen(3000);` put this line end of the **Backend Index.js file** instead of putting at starting. make sure that you have declare all the routes before app start. ( Follow proper hierarchy )

Comment: Hierarchy should be,

1st, Import modules,

2nd apply middlewares ( eg, `app.use(cores)`)

3rd, configure server, and  define routes

4th. `app.listen(port, () => console.log(``Listening on ${port}...``));`

so, Following this, we can assure that we have done setup properly, then we can look around the actual problems. try this, and make sure that your app is listening on correct port or not.

Comment: Hey @akhsar tried doing it in Hierarchy same issue 
Can there be any issue in Database Config like do i have to mention Port There or something ?

Comment: Can you try `axios.post("http://localhost:3000/product/add", formData)`

Comment: @Daniel Tried this Not working Can there be any issue in Sql Config like port number?

Comment: @KamranMemon I Don't think so. You sad that `<form ...>` worked. I have created the project locally (no DB) and the HTTP request works find. Can you try maybe uploading the codebase you have to `GitHub` so we will be 100% on the same page.

Comment: @Daniel Below is the link for Backend Api and Frontend 
https://github.com/kammy1996/ecommerce-backend-api
https://github.com/kammy1996/ecommerce-admin-frontend 
My Email: kamranmemon25@gmail.com 
Please update once if you find Anything 
thank you very much

Comment: I run the code without DB and it ran fine. Try to remove the DB flow for now (like produce/get). If you still having HTTP issues I would say suggest trying to change ports

Comment: @Daniel Tried Changing ports get request works fine with every port and POST request is not happening

Comment: try (without DB) `curl -X POST  localhost:3000/product/add -v` from the same host

Comment: Hey @Daniel thank you very much for your support the issue was very silly

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer I was missing a middleware `app.use(bodyParser.json)` in *index.js* and because of that there was no value going into database and thus, there was a network error.

Answer (score -1):

I realized that, you are sending a PUT request to backend but your API controller receiving POST requests. So, Don't they have to be same type of request ?

Comment: @kaam kemal Sorry thats a typo i have changed it million times from post to put and get